# Can I Deploy a Plain Old .war File to Heroku?

Tags: java, heroku

I am interested in Heroku but can't seem to find the answer to my particular situation.

I have a couple of apps developed in 'pure' Java EE. No Spring, no Play! just servlets and JSPs. I would like to deploy them via Heroku, but their text on their website keeps mentioning  various frameworks. I hand roll my own dependency injection and prefer it that way.

Is this supported on Heroku?

Thanks-in-advance,

Guido

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heroku Dev Center has an [article on war-file deployment](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment).

You can use both the Eclipse plugin and the Heroku Toolbelt command-line tool.